# Restrict access to page via script Appmaker

Tags: security, restriction, google-app-maker

I've been working on an app with Google App Maker for a bit and I'm trying to restrict access to a certain page via a script in the Security part of my page:

> [image: Security part of my page]
>
> ```
> canViewDas (user, userRoles)
> ```

Even though my script returns false, I can still access to the page (in preview and published).

- Is it because I'm the owner of the app?
- Is this some kind of bug?
- Am I using this feature wrong?

I tried just putting "false" instead of my script and I still have access to the page.

Comment: If you are the developer of the application you are automatically listed as an Admin role and that role has unrestricted access to everything. Also, if you are trying to restrict access to the page for specific user roles, you can set the security setting to 'Roles' instead of 'Script' and then you can add your roles that you want to have access for the page.

Comment: In my app, users are either allowed, have a partial access or are not allowed according to some parameters stored in Cloud SQL so Roles doesn't really fit my need even though I tought about it. 
Still thank you so much for your answer !